# Angular 6 "global" service that runs functions on every page load and in background

Tags: angular, service, singleton, angular6

I have an app that has several "modules" that run. `app.module` loads `core.module` and then core module needs to run a `global.service` that runs on every page constantly that is doing session checks/etc.

For example, every 10 seconds the service needs to call the backend and check the "session status".

I want to avoid putting this logic in `app.component` if possible and instead have all of the logic in a service that is constantly running and performing these checks and handling them appropriately.

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: @dAxx_ the problem is I'm unsure of how to get global.service to run on every page as a "singleton"

Comment: if you create a service and declare its Injection as @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
}) it will be provided by Root (Main Module of the application) and will be a singleton. (you dont have to provide it anywhere, it will automatically do it.)

Comment: @dAxx_ so if I add that to my global.service can I just call a function from the constructor that uses an RXJS interval to run logic every 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm doing something similar my only concern is performance... how did it worked for you?

Comment: It worked fine, on core.component init I start an rxjs interval that calls a global service every 10s and runs appropriate business logic.